# Vaadin: Several browser tabs and no initial reload

Tags: java, vaadin

This is Vaadin's official solution to multi-tabs and out of sync problem:
https://vaadin.com/web/joonas/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Supporting+Multible+Tabs#_36_messageScroll1791001

If I remove the line

w.open(new ExternalResource(w.getURL()));

in the presented code, the application webpage is not refreshed when opening additional tabs, I don't get a different url for application tab and I got no "out of sync" errors so far.

I don't see the relation between having a separate window class (and isolating window-specific state in this class) to the fact of having a different app url for each tab that opens the application.

Is the code above required?

Thanks in advance.